# Mixture model as a prior distribution

Tags: machine-learning, hierarchical-bayesian

I've just started working with Bayesian models.
My question is in the context of hierarchical Bayesian model.

Suppose you have *n* models to train. However, some of these models are similar to each other in some sense and I could assume that they their parameters are drawn from the same prior distribution. Another subgroup of that models are also similar to each other and their parameters share the same prior distribution. And it repeats for all subgroups (unknown in advance).

So, my question is: Is it possible to use a mixture of distributions as a prior distribution for all these *n* models? In such hierarchical model each component of the mixture model respond to a group of models. The underlying idea is to cluster these *n* models by employing a mixture model as a prior distribution.

Does it make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand this question. 

A hierarchical model often implies that a posterior predictive distribution on a parameter is a mixture distribution, so maybe there's some confusion here. 

For a particular parameter, the prior within the hierarchy can be any kind of distribution. However, it's more common to use something simple, like a conjugate prior and allow the complexity/mixture modeling to come from the hierarchical structure itself.

Comment: I found this paper "[Multi-Task Learning for Classification with Dirichlet Process Priors](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v8/xue07a.html)" which employs a similar approach, they use a Dirichlet process as prior distribution over the *n* models. As the author says: "Dirichlet process model has an implicit mechanism
of clustering samples into groups".

Comment: If what you're asking is whether hierarchical models can be used to model mixture distributions and infer latent mixture components, the answer is yes.